# How do i grey out the input field and the submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to grey out [these two things](http://doorsplit.heroku.com/) the song input field and the submit button until the user enters and artist. Is there an easy way to do this via JQuery.

the id of the artist input field is #request_artist

Comment: External links can break. Please let your question be self contained

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var artist = ('#request_artist');
var song = ('#request_song');
var assubmit = ('#request_submit');

song.attr('disabled', true);
assubmit.attr('disabled', true);

artist.change(function() {
  if(artist.val() > 0) {
    song.attr('disabled', false);
    assubmit.attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    song.attr('disabled', true);
    assubmit.attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

for the input field, the submit button should be equal
$('#request_artist').attr('disabled', true);

Answer (score 3):

The one liner code would be :

```
     <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="txt1" />
     <input type="button" name="name" id="btn1" disabled="disabled" value="Submit" />

<script type="text/javascript">

            $("#txt1").keyup(function () {
                $("#btn1").attr("disabled", $.trim($("#txt1").val()) != "" ? "" : "disabled");
            });


</script>
```

Comment: It's not code golf here, why do you *have* to squash your code onto a single line? And how is having fewer lines make this solution superior?

Comment: I am sorry, my intention is to make use of Jquery Chaining feature.