# disable input field totally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-ui

I have an input on a form where I am displaying an amount owed. Basically if the amount owed is zero, I add a special class called "paid" and I can **$(".paid")** using jquery. All of this is working well.

The question is, how do I prevent users form clicking or entering text or doing anything else with these inputs ?

This is my finction so far.

```
function disablepaid(){
    $(".paid").on("click", function(){
        alert("Do disabling stuff now");
    });
}
```

In some other posts I saw people trying **jquery blur()**, and seting the disabled attribute as seen here [How do i grey out the input field and the submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746115/how-do-i-grey-out-the-input-field-and-the-submit-button)

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: The answer is to set the `disabled` property to `true`.

Comment: why dont you show this by ajax ...like if condition match only than show the fild since i can disable js

Comment: @NullPointer - surely if you disable the js then the ajax call wouldn't work either..?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the `disabled` attribute on the input..

something like:

```
    function disablepaid(){
        $(".paid").on("click", function(){
            alert("Do disabling stuff now");
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        });
    }
```

If at any time you need to renable it then:

```
    $(".paid").prop('disabled', false);
```

**Update**

Also, rather than allowing the user to click on the paid input field and THEN disabling it, why not disable it when you set the zero amount?

Comment: Thanks man, I preferred this as I am using the newest jquery version

Comment: @Binaryrespawn, you're welcome. Once you get to grips with the library you'll be amazed at what you can do with little code :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `prop()` and set the disabled property to `true`

```
$(".paid").on("click", function(){
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);

        // or  
        this.disabled = true; 
});
```

Comment: Or just `this.disabled = true;`

Comment: @Pointy - yea i just added that

Answer (score 0):

You can disable your input

```
$(".paid").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: Better to just use `this.disabled = true;` in the "click" handler.  Using `.attr()` like that has been sort-of wrong since jQuery 1.6.